# How to turn off Bluetooth pairing on Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth

I have written a bluetooth client app and a bluetooth server app based on the example at https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html.

The server app is running on Raspberry Pi and the client runs on a Ubuntu 18.04 box.

The communication works as expected.

I noticed that, the first time the client connects, a system window pops up (on the client Ubuntu box) asking for pairing request.

My client code will ultimately go on a device that has no display. I cannot afford to have any user interaction for the client/server communication.

Q1. The client is making a socket call:

```
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
```

Is there a flag I can pass that could be used to suppress pairing? In my client, neither the client nor the server really care for secure connectivity.

Q2. When I run the tool "bluetoothctl" on both devices, I see the paired device listed on the client box but I don't see any paired device at all on the server device. How is this possible? I thought pairing is always a two-way trust relationship. And how is that the communication is still working?

Q3. Is pairing a requirement for simple bluetooth client/server communication?

Answer (score 1):

When in `bluetoothctl` on the client, then it is worth checking a few things.

As well as looking at the device paired status, check if the server device is trusted and if the Serial Port profile is listed.

```
[bluetooth]# info B8:27:EB:22:57:E0 
Device B8:27:EB:22:57:E0 (public)
        Name: SeeMe
        Alias: SeeMe
        Class: 0x00480000
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: no
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

You can trust the device in bluetoothctl with `trust <dev_addr>`

The Serial Port Profile will appear in the list if you have the server running when you did the pairing.

You can also tell BlueZ that your client device does not have input or output devices to use with pairing. Within bluetoothctl.

```
[bluetooth]# agent off
Agent unregistered
[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput
Agent registered
[bluetooth]#
```

I would hope that is enough, but beyond that, most profiles are registered with the Profile API on the server where it is possible to specify the RequireAuthentication and RequireAuthorization options. Not sure how that would be set in your setup.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt#n85